# Was there a toy called "Harry Potter Concoction"?

Tags: harry-potter, toys

I have scoured the Internet, but I can't find any evidence of a toy called "Harry Potter Concoction".

I have a vivid memory of a commercial that had a song with a low, deep voice and the lyrics:

> Make a concoction...A Harry Potter concoction

If I remember correctly, it was similar to [Creepy Crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creepy_Crawlers)

I am trying to determine if this was some sort of crazy dream or if it really existed.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Professor-Snapes-Potions-Edible-Activity/dp/B000VENRN2? Or http://www.amazon.com/Harry-Potter-Polyjuice-Potion-Maker/dp/B0013ABI9S?

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to check out the Polyjuice toy?

Answer (score 2):

Could you be remembering the [Polyjuice Potion Maker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013ABI9S)? I'm not familiar with the commercial you mentioned, but it is conceivable that someone could sing a song like that about a potion making kit, even if the kit's name was different. I have not been able to find other Harry Potter products that involve "concocting" anything, although there is a [Wizard's Potion Set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KIZL6VE) available that is not official Harry Potter merchandise.

Comment: I sent an email to Mattel's press department to try and get more information. If I don't hear back I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure it was called Polyjuice Potion making kit. I used to see them on TV ads all the time!

[image]